# Alias one URL to another

Tags: apache-2.2, url

I have a mod-wsgi script running which is aliased to `/test`.

I would like to alias the URL `/prod` to `/test`. So essentially, `/test` loads, but the URL says `/prod`. It is a single-page application.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html, then in your VirtualHost settings or in your `.htaccess` put something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/prod(/?.*)$ /test/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: As this is a script `^/prod$ /test` may be more applicable